# "OpenCV: invalid device function" error in EmguCV project on first cuda call

Tags: c#, opencv, cuda, emgucv

I'm trying to run a project I found in a guide (Windows Forms App [.NET Framework], EmguCV). I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, and I obtained three dependencies from NuGet Package Manager: Emgu.CV, Emhu.CV.Bitmap, Emgu.CV.runtime.windows.cuda.

The Function `CudaInvoke.GetCudaDevicesSummary();` returns

Has cuda: true;
Cuda devices: 1;
Device 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Unfortunately, the first function call - `CudaInvoke.BilateralFilter(cudaImage, resultMat, 150, 380, 380);` throws an exception:

> Emgu.CV.Util.CvException
> Message=OpenCV: invalid device function

I saw similar questions, but there were about OpenCV C++ with Cmake project. And what I need to do in my situation?

Comment: This usually means that the code has been compiled for an architecture that does not match the GPU you are running on.  You might have to rebuild those packages, or find an alternate source of those packages that run on your GPU. I wouldn't be able to give you a detailed recipe, but [this](https://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Building_from_Git) may be a starting point.  I wouldn't be surprised if the configuration process asks for GPU architecture target(s) to compile for.  You will want to get the compute capability of your GPU, I believe it is 5.0.

Comment: also see [here](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/578) for the type of build work needed.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes it's 5.0. I will try to figure it out with the links you gave me!